# How to exclude from grep double colons?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to find lines with words not preceded by double colons (::).
Example

void myClass::doMything() // I don't want this line

myObj->doMyThing() // I want this line

My goal is to get the lines where some methods are used, but not where the methods are defined.

I try with this command :

```
grep --color=always -rwna "methodName" --include=*.cpp | grep -v "::methodName"
```

but it doesn't work : it keeps extracting also lines containing
::methodName

I've also tried by writing

```
grep --color=always -rwna "methodName" --include=*.cpp | grep -v "\:\:methodName"

egrep --color=always -rwna "methodName" --include=*.cpp | egrep -v "\:\:methodName"
```

but neither works.

What should I do ?

Comment: Try something like: `grep -v '::[[:alpha:]]'  Input_file`. It will simply remove lines which has double colon followed by alphabet(I am checking single occurrence you can add `+` after `[[:alpha:]]` also for more than 1 occurrence of alphabet).

Comment: cpp files are source files, which means, they are text files. Why you put `-a` option there?

Comment: @Kent : I have this habit since during a search in an external library codebase I found that some source files were seen as binary by the file system

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you, but it continues extracting also the lines with the double colon. It's like if it's invisible to grep...

Comment: @crillion, ok how about trying like `grep -v '::[[:alpha:]]*'  Input_file` once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to make it work.

I've tried linux_beginner's suggestion:

```
grep -Eno '(::)?myMethodName' path/to/one/of/the/files.cpp | grep -v '::myMethodName'
```

with a **single** file and this **works**. (I found I prefer not using the o option, because I also want to se how it's used).

In this search I need anyway to use multiple files. So I've also tried to include **more** files :

```
grep -Eno '(::)?myMethodName' --include=*.cpp | grep -v '::myMethodName'
```

but in this case it remains like **stuck** in the search (maybe it triggers some slow scripting ? perl or python ?).

I've checked RavinderSingh13's command. Taken in a single instance, it can capture the lines with double colon(and only them, correctly), both on single file or in multiple files :

```
grep -rna '::myMethodName' path/to/one/of/the/file.cpp

grep -rna '::myMethodName' --include=*.cpp
```

but there must **not** be the **-w** switch, so the following:

```
grep -rna '::myMethodName' path/to/one/of/the/file.cpp

grep -rna '::myMethodName' --include=*.cpp
```

don't get any result.
RavinderSingh13's suggestion put inside the pipelining doesn't manage to filter out the double colon lines (my original goal), either with single or multiple files :

```
grep -rwna 'myMethodName' path/to/one/of/the/files.cpp | grep -v '::[[:alpha:]]+'
```

-> extracts both myMethodName and ::myMethodName from the chosen file

```
grep -rwna 'myMethodName' --include=*.cpp | grep -v '::[[:alpha:]]+'
```

-> extracts both myMethodName and ::myMethodName from all the cpp files

Now, how I could solve:
usually, when I concatenate grep commands I also add to the first of them the switch **--color=always**, which preserves results coloring also across the piping of multiple commands.
But that... was the culprit !

i.e., doing

```
grep --color=always -rwna 'myMethodName' --include=*.cpp | grep -v '::myMethodName'
```

preserves the color in results, but sadly **fails** to exclude lines containing ::myMethodName, while

```
grep -rwna 'myMethodName' --include=*.cpp | grep -v '::myMethodName'
```

gives **colorless but correct** results (manages to filter out double column lines).

The distribution on which I've experimented these codes and behaviours is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
Grep version : grep (GNU grep) 3.4

Thanks everybody for the interest.

Answer (score 1):

Although grep is probably most common used tool among all linux CLI tools and is used by every1 and everywhere... still doesnt mean its perfect. The thing you are trying to achieve is not achievable with basic grep's regex - you need python/perl regex here.

As a workaround (I assume you are trying to only find line where method is invoked) you can try:

```
grep -Eno "(::)?methodName" your_input_files | grep -v "::methodName"
```

`-n` to prints line number and I believe it will give convenience to you

`-o` to prints only matched part, but I use it here to split output - to have each match in separate line (if you have 5x methodName in line of code you will have 5 lines in grep's output)

`(::)?` to find distinguish if its declaration or invokation of methodName, we will need it when 2nd grep comes to play...

`grep -v` ...and here it comes, to get rid of what you dont want

I guess you want to use maaaaany times so you can even try to make a function into your .bashrc

```
find_invocations () {
# below example goes through current dir, but you can improve it :)
grep --color=yes -Eno "(::)?$1" * 2>/dev/null | grep -v "::$1"
}
```

in above function you might go risky and use `$1.*` instead of `$1` but an unpleasant case is if you have both methodname and ::methodName in same line AFAIR my C++ lessons (ages ago - anno 2010) `methodName::methodName` is a constructor...

...sorry for bad english